# Debian Linux and Gnokii: Unlock SIM

Tags: debian, sim

I just got my Nokia Internet Stick CS-17 ... I want to use it not for surfing the web, but to send and receive sms. I tried it with my Fedora Linux and it works just great.

Now the thing is: On Fedora I got X installed and it asked me to type in the PIN. Now I want it for my Debian System, but it doesn't ask me anything.

When I plug the Data stick in, there comes an error message saying the following:

```
[ 1672.793322] sr0: CDROM (ioctl) error, command: Get event status notification 4a 01 00 00 10 00 00 00 08 00
(the error message 3 times)
```

Does anyone know a solution to unlock the SIM to use the Internet Stick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This page, [Nokia Internet Stick CS-10 on Linux](http://islascruz.org/html/index.php/blog/show/Nokia-Internet-Stick-CS-10-on-Linux.html), describes one method of making it work.

> [...] you just need to umount the device using "eject", This is because this stick identifies itself as a "CD-ROM" and when you use "eject" it changes its behaviour and start acting like a modem.
>
> [...] You just need to create this rule in /etc/udev/rules.d/90-nokia-zerocd.rules
>
> ```
> SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0421", SYSFS{idProduct}=="060c", ACTION=="add", PROGRAM=="nokia-testcd %M %s{serial}", RUN+="/usr/bin/eject -s %k", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
> ```
>
> As you can see, it depends on a program "nokia-testcd", it is just a simple bash script with this code:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
>
> # Don't eject if flag in place
> if [ -f /etc/udev/nokia-zerocd-noeject ]; then
>    exit 1
> fi
>
> # Extract USB serial into major and minor numbers
> minor=`echo $2 | sed 's/.[0-9]*\.//'`
> major=`echo $2 | sed 's/\.[0-9]*$//'`
>
> # Compare with current software version
> if [ "$major" -gt "0" ] ||  [ "$minor" -gt "10" ]; then
>    exit 1
> fi
>
> # Clean exit on match
> exit 0
> ```
>
> Just copy the code in /lib/udev/ and make it executable (chmod 0755 /lib/udev/nokia-testcd). Once you have written the udev rule, and "installed" the nokia-testcd script just restart udev (or reload it) and plug your Nokia CS-10.